# How to get value from Parsed JSON Object using Array.prototype.find() or Array.Prototype.filter()

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a parsed JSON Object like this.

```
[ { id: 973276, raw: 'Apple Tree Childcare', extractedData: null }, 
{ id: 973576, raw: 'Yes', extractedData: 'Yes' }, 
{ id: 973567, raw: 'Road', extractedData: null } ]
```

Now on this, I am looking to get value of `raw` or `extractedData`, when I know value of `id`.

I tried `find()` and `filter()` functions, but couldn't get it. Here's my code.

```
function getSchoolName(school) { 
    return school.id === '973276';
}
var replies = JSON.parse(event.replyHistory);
console.log(replies); // output is above

console.log(replies.filter(getSchoolName));//[]
console.log(replies.find(getSchoolName)); //undefined
```

Can someone guide me the right way to do it? TIA

Comment: you are comparing a string to a int. remove the quotes in your getSchoolName function

Comment: Shame on me, i missed it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
return school.id === '973276';
```

'973276' is string
but your object id is number
you can change code to

```
return school.id == '973276';
```

Comment: Actually, I solved it using `return school.id === 973276`. Removing quotes from number.